# VS2015 - SSIS custom component - bespoke form not showing, instead get Advanced Editor

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to develop a custom source component for SSIS in VS2015. After struggling to even get the component's to display in the SSIS Toolbox I've managed to get that, but when clicking on the component instead of displaying the bespoke form it goes directly to the Advanced Editor. I've implemented the class exactly as described in the Microsoft documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136029.aspx

but it still doesn't show.

I've used the

```
namespace CustomImporter
{
[DtsPipelineComponent(
    DisplayName = "Custom importer",
    Description = "Custom Importer",
    IconResource = "CustomImporter.ico",
    UITypeName = "CustomImporter.CustomImporterUI, CustomImporter.CustomImporter, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b0a5b72a437255d",
    ComponentType = ComponentType.SourceAdapter)
]

public class CustomImporter : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent
{
//code to implement the class
}
```

and then in the forms class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Design;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;

namespace CustomImporter
{
    class CustomImporterUI : IDtsComponentUI
    {

        #region Members

            IDTSComponentMetaData100 metaData;
            IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

        #endregion

        #region IDtsComponentUI Member

        bool IDtsComponentUI.Edit(IWin32Window parentWindow, Variables variables, Connections connections)
        {
            frmMain editor = new frmMain(metaData, serviceProvider, variables, connections);

            DialogResult result = editor.ShowDialog(parentWindow);

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        void IDtsComponentUI.Help(IWin32Window parentWindow) {}

        void IDtsComponentUI.Initialize(IDTSComponentMetaData100 dtsComponentMetadata, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            this.metaData = dtsComponentMetadata;
            this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        void IDtsComponentUI.New(IWin32Window parentWindow){}

        void IDtsComponentUI.Delete(IWin32Window parentWindow){}

        public void Initialize(IDTSComponentMetaData100 dtsComponentMetadata, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Store the component metadata.
            this.metaData = dtsComponentMetadata;
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Is there anything obvious that looks wrong? I'm not an expert in C# so I don't really know how the DtsPipeline code that specifies the UITypeName parameters should look. In the Microsoft reference link it doesn't match up with the rest of the class names or assembly name, but I've made sure that when I register the component into the GAC or uninstall it the PublicKeyToken matches what I see in the Command Prompt window so it can't be that. I know this is extremely fiddly, but I can't see any documentation anywhere to get the form to show.

I've registered the dll in the GAC and copied the dll to the following folders:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\PipelineComponents
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\PipelineComponents

And it is appearing in SSIS Toolbox.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did You resolve this? I have the same issue and would appreciate if You share how You solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I think your UITypeName attribute is wrong.  It should be the

```
"namespace.classThatInheritsFromIDtsComponentUI, AssemblyName"
```

try

```
UITypeName = "CustomImporter.CustomImporterUI, CustomImporter, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b0a5b72a437255d"
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue as well. After banging my head on the table for two days, I noticed that, when building the projects, VS listed some warnings(Code `CS1762`) regarding the `Embed Interop Types` property of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap` and `Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap` assemblies references in the UI project.

A few days ago, I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47072794/8873788) for another issue, which also dealt with the `Embed Interop Types` properties of those references, and the solution was to set their values to `false`. I therefore tried applying it here as well, and surprisingly it solved the problem.