# Method not found SetDataTypeProperties in custom SSIS component

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to build a simple custom SSIS component which looks at a single input column and validates it, creating an output column of type bool depending on the value of each row.

I've successfully built an even simpler component that takes a value and transforms it: that doesn't require fiddling with the output columns. In this instance I need to take in a string and output a boolean and the component needs to know that it outputs a boolean so I can feed the value into a conditional split.

I'm struggling to add the output columns. Based on [code samples from Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135931.aspx), I have done this:

```
public override DTSValidationStatus Validate()
{
    IDTSOutput100 output = ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection[0];

    IDTSOutputColumn100 outputcol = output.OutputColumnCollection.New();
    outputcol.Name = "IsValid";
    outputcol.SetDataTypeProperties(DataType.DT_BOOL, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    return DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISVALID;
}
```

And then I attempt to populate it during the ProcessInput step:

```
public override void ProcessInput(int inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
{
    while (buffer.NextRow())
    {
        string str = buffer.GetString(0);
        buffer.SetBoolean(0, IsValid(str)); // validation code not relevant
    }
}
```

When I try to use this component in the package, I get this error:

```
The component has detected potential metadata corruption during validation.
Error at Data Flow Task [Uppercase [24]]: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSOutputColumn100.SetDataTypeProperties(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.DataType, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)'.
   at EmailValidation.Uppercase.Validate()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostValidate(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)
```

Searching on this error message has yielded nothing of value.

In the original sample - and some other tutorials online - adding output columns is done by looping through the input column and adding an additional output for each. I have tried this and get the same error.

I have also tried moving the output column code from `Validate` to `OnInputPathAttached` which still yields the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of SSIS are you using?

Comment: @mallan1121 thanks for looking. It's sql 2014, which is 120 in the pipeline folder

Comment: Do you have a reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper` component in your assembly? Is it available at computer where the error is taking place? The error is saying that it cannot locate method at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper assembly.

Comment: @Ferdipux that's helpful but it's a yes to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On investigation this appears to be a bug in SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015. I have built, deployed and used a custom component with customised output columns in an Integration Services package in Visual Studio 2013. However, the same tool deployed in a package in 2015 causes the error described.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's still relevant, I encountered a similar issue (With the `ComponentMetaData` property rather than `SetDataTypeProperties`), and the solution that worked for me was setting the `Embed Interop Types` property of the `Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap` and `Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap` references to `false`.

I found this solution [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/support-multi-targeting-in-your-custom-components#common-errors). It's listed as a solution for getting an `InvalidCastException`, but it seems relevant for whenever you're referencing the `DTSPipelineWrap` or the `DTSRuntimeWrap` assemblies in custom components.